# How to add properties to a styled material-ui props class in react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am wanting to use material-ui, using react and typescript. I would like to pass properties to the components, but cannot figure out how to do it. I am using the react-typescript example from the material-UI repo. What I tried is as follows:

Add a properties interface:

```
const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      textAlign: 'center',
      paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit * 20,
    },
  });

interface IndexProps
  extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  myText: string;
}
```

then define my component, and use the property:

```
class Index extends React.Component<IndexProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.classes.root}>
        <Typography variant="display1" gutterBottom>
          Material-UI
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="subheading" gutterBottom>
          example project text=[{this.props.myText}]
        </Typography>
        <Button variant="raised" color="secondary" >
          Super Secret Password
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRoot(withStyles(styles)(Index));
```

On my Index page I put:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Index from './pages/index';

ReactDOM.render(<Index myText="Foo" />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

But get a compile error:

```
(5,18): Type '{ myText: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated

For completeness, my `packages.json` file is:

```
{
  "name": "create-react-app-with-typescript",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "src/index.tsx",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "latest",
    "@types/react": "*",
    "@types/react-dom": "*",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-scripts-ts": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "*",
    "@types/node": "*",
    "typescript": "latest"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-ts start",
    "build": "react-scripts-ts build",
    "test": "react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts-ts eject"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using [this definition of `withRoot`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/59b630ee5bb00c3b3373a6c182102b73f9c9a56e/examples/create-react-app-with-typescript/src/withRoot.tsx).  If you hover over the call to `withRoot`, you'll see its return type is:

```
(props: object) => JSX.Element
```

This is wrong: the props type should be `{myText: string}`, not `object`.  If you go to the definition of `withRoot`, you'll see where this is coming from:

```
function withRoot(Component: React.ComponentType) {
  function WithRoot(props: object) {
```

Those lines should be replaced with:

```
function withRoot<P>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) {
  function WithRoot(props: P) {
```

You could consider sending a pull request to fix this in the original example.

### Round 2

(Referring to the example in the comment)

This turns out to have an unrelated root cause.  I see the error on `src/App.tsx` line 60:

```
let drawer = <ItemsList myText="asdf" history={history} />;
```

referring to the definition at the bottom of `src/components/ItemsList.tsx`:

```
export default withStyles(styles)<{}>(connect(mapStateToProps)(withWidth()(ItemsList))
);
```

For starters, get rid of that explicit type argument `<{}>`, which is overriding whatever is being determined automatically; I'm surprised that didn't give you an error by itself.  Then the error in `App.tsx` changes to say that the `location` prop is missing.  You might already recognize this as one of the `RouteComponentProps`, but I didn't, so I proceeded to look at the entire set of props of the final component by adding the following to `ItemsList.tsx`:

```
type PropsOf<C> = C extends React.ComponentType<infer P> ? P : never;
const ItemsListWrapped = withStyles(styles)(connect(mapStateToProps)(withWidth()(ItemsList));
type FinalProps = PropsOf<typeof ItemsListWrapped>;
let x: FinalProps;
x.  // look at completion menu here (Ctrl-Space in Visual Studio Code)
```

Unfortunately, these complicated type operations give rise to type expressions that are hard to understand or even get truncated in the hover pop-up, so the best way I found to see all the props was to look at the completion menu, as indicated.  Then we see four unexpected props: `history`, `location`, `match`, and `staticContext`.  If we look at all the places these might have come from, hopefully they are recognizable as coming from the `ItemsList.Props extends RouteComponentProps<void>`.  Indeed, that declaration is wrong because you are not using `ItemsList` as a route component nor manually passing all of those props, nor does `ItemsList` actually use any of the props except for `history`, which you declare again (and do pass).  So just remove `RouteComponentProps<void>` from the extends list.

As we've seen, type errors on using a wrapped React component can have many different causes.  I hope I've given you some sense of how to track down future such errors yourself.

Comment: Thanks. That solves the problem for this simple case, where the main element is the one using `withRoot`. But in more complex/real scenarios, where I have multiple levels of components, I still get this error. Any ideas? (will try to put together a sample)

Comment: I'll need to see the example.

Comment: I have posted a sample here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E2Ed1SUqRzLRaB-J1-HgUsSsV6gZdwza/view?usp=sharing. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is way awesome. Love the way you interrogated the type.

Comment: PR to fix `withRoot` upstream is https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/12712.